# How do I randomize quiz questions in actionscript3?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, random

I have a quiz game in flash; basically you need to type the answer to answer 4 questions. In the end, it will show you the score and your answers vs. The correct answers.

1. I need help on how to randomize the questions (without repeating the question)
2. In the end the correct answer needs to match the order in which the player answered the question.

I attached the pictures below.

[image: end game screen]

The code: Frame 1

```
stop();
var nQNumber:Number = 0;
var aQuestions:Array = new Array();
var aCorrectAnswers:Array = new Array("Jupiter", "Mars", "war", "Titan");
var aUserAnswers:Array = new Array();
aQuestions[0] = "What is the biggest planet in our solar system?";
aQuestions[1] = "Which planet in our solar system is the 4th planet from the 
sun?";
aQuestions[2] = "Mars is named after the Roman god of ___.";
aQuestions[3] = "What is the name of Saturn's largest moon?";
questions_txt.text = aQuestions[nQNumber];
submit_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, quiz);
function quiz(e:MouseEvent):void{
aUserAnswers.push(answers_txt.text);
answers_txt.text = "";
nQNumber++;
if(nQNumber < aQuestions.length){
  questions_txt.text = aQuestions[nQNumber]}
else{
  nextFrame()}
}
```

Frame 2

```
var nScore:Number = 0;
for(var i:Number = 0; i < aQuestions.length; i++){
this["userAnswer" + i + "_txt"].text = aUserAnswers[i];
this["correctAnswer" + i + "_txt"].text = aCorrectAnswers[i];
if(aUserAnswers[i].toUpperCase() == aCorrectAnswers[i].toUpperCase()){
nScore++}
if(i == aQuestions.length - 1){
score_txt.text = nScore.toString()}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way to handle this, would be to create an array to hold your questions that need to be asked,  randomize the array, then remove the corresponding question from the array at the time it is asked.  Then when that array is empty, move on to your recap screen.

Here is one of many ways you could accomplish this:

First, let's simplify this by using objects instead of a whole bunch of arrays. Your object will have properties for all the relevant information

```
//create an array that will hold all your questions
var questions:Array = [];

//add a new question object to the array, repeat for all questions
questions.push({
    question: "What is the biggest planet in our solar system?",
    correctAnswer: "Jupiter"
    userAnswer: null,
    correct: false
});
```

Next, let's randomize that array:

```
//sort the array with the sort function below
questions.sort(randomizeArray);

//this sorts in a random way
function randomizeArray(a,b):int {
    return(Math.random() > 0.5) ? 1: -1;
}
```

Now, let's copy the array to keep track of which questions need to be asked still

```
var askQuestions:Array = questions.concat(); //concat with no parameters returns a new shallow copy of the array
var curQuestion; //create a var to hold the current question
```

Now, create a function to ask the next question:

```
function askNextQuestion():void {
    //check if there are any more questions to ask
    if(askQuestions.length > 0){

        //get the next question object
        curQuestion = askQuestions.shift(); //shift removes the first item of an array, and returns that item
        questions_txt.text = curQuestion.question;
        answers_txt.text = "";

    }else{
        //all questions have been asked, show your recap screen
        finish();
    }
}
```

You'll need a function to run when you click the answer button:

```
function submitAnswer(e:Event = null):void {
    //if there is a current question
    if(curQuestion){
        curQuestion.userAnswer = answers_txt.text;
        curQuestion.correct = curQuestion.correctAnswer.toUpperCase() == answers_txt.text.toUpperCase();
    }

    //ask the next question
    askNextQuestion();
}
```

And a function that runs when all questions have been asked:

```
function finish():void {
    var score:int = 0;

    //go through the array and count how many are correct and recap
    for(var i:int=0; i<questions.length;i++){
        if(questions[i].correct) score++;
        trace("Question " + (i+1) + ":",questions[i].question); //arrays are 0 based, so we add 1 to the index (i) so that it says "Question 1:" for the first question instead of "Question 0:"
        trace("You answered:",questions[i].userAnswer);
        trace("Correct Answer:", questions[i].correctAnswer);
        trace(questions[i].correct ? "You were correct" : "You were wrong","\n"); //this is shorthand if statement,  \n is a line break
    }

    score_txt.text = score + " out of " + questions.length;
}
```

And of course, to get things started you just do:  `askNextQuestion()`

Comment: when i tried this code i get this error TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Untitled_2_Scene1_fla::MainTimeline/askNextQuestion()
 at Untitled_2_Scene1_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
what is the "q" supposed be in questions_txt.text = q.question; and on the q.correct in finish function?

Comment: q is a typo on the first bit (should be `curQuestion` instead of `q`).    In the for each loop at the end of my answer,  q represents the question object of the current iteration of the loop (though I see I forgot to put `var` infront of it`).   I updated the answer to fix two typos/errors.

Comment: In regards to the new information in your question (since I answered).  The `questions` array will be in the same order that was asked.  (after changing `questions.pop` to `questions.shift`)   So when the quiz is finished, you can iterate through each question to recap - I made an example using traces (which show in the output window when testing/running it in AnimateCC/FlashPro

Comment: thanks it works the way i want to now, but i wonder why is says on trace "You were correct" all the time even when the answer is wrong. I made "curQuestion.correct = curQuestion.userAnswer.toUpperCase() == answers_txt.text.toUpperCase();" in submitAnswer function a comment, when i did that it says "You were wrong" every time. i tweaked the finish function so that it shows the real score in the dynamic textbox,but in trace it still says "You were wrong" because i commented "curQuestion.correct = curQuestion.userAnswer.toUpperCase() == answers_txt.text.toUpperCase();".

Comment: Just a typo,  you should be comparing the correct answer to the text box.  As i wrote it you're comparing the user's answer to the user's answer (which will always be true)  I'll update the answer and fix that.   If you feel this answer answers your question, consider marking it as such (green check) to aid future visitors in quickly seeing the solution.  It also increases your (and my) reputation

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the nifty feature called [Math.random()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#random())? Multiply the result of Math.random() by your desired random generation range, round it, and select a random question in your array using the number.